# SHA1 hash for OSX 10.11.2 El Capitan public release?

Tags: macos

I have downloaded the OSX 10.11.2 El Capitan app from App Store, and I found it downloaded it from local China server even though my apple ID wasn't for China store, and I am living in China, the download IP of `storedownloadd` indicated :

`hpcc-download.cnc.ccgslb.com.cn
183.131.116.32
222.246.232.146
115.231.22.17
115.231.22.75
61.153.56.138
183.134.20.67
183.134.20.74`

I am concerned about the genuine of the copy, so is anyone know what the SHA1 of InstallESD.dmg? I really appreciate it. Just to make sure its genuine copy, and you know, the GhostXcode malware came out from China mainland.

Comment: This page may be useful: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is,

2b11b8b618a2e5100507c3c432363081db65c4c8

Which is downloaded from Apple Store and server located in North America.

Comment: Nice answer. Would you consider editing in the method you use to determine the hash? That will help many more people than just listing the result.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/drduh/OS-X-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/blob/master/InstallESD_Hashes.csv

Comment: @uwotm8 Really good, I have been looking for that long time, and if I have found that early, I won't have this question!